# code optimisation

Tags: android, optimization

i have this code:

```
private Bitmap disk1, disk2, disk3;
private ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
......
disk1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.disk01);
disk1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(disk1, 0, 0, origW, origH, matrix, true);
disk2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.disk02);
disk2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(disk2, 0, 0, origW, origH, matrix, true);
disk3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.disk03);
disk3 = Bitmap.createBitmap(disk3, 0, 0, origW, origH, matrix, true);

bitmapArray.add(disk1);
bitmapArray.add(disk2);
bitmapArray.add(disk3);
```

i think to optimise code i can use this construction without bitmaps (with for loop):

```
 bitmapArray.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.disk01), 0, 0, origW, origH, matrix, true));
```

but i'm little confused: it will store the result of methods or it will be call those methods every time when i try to get *bitmapArray.get(0)*?

thanx

---

update: i will use array after in handler callback to change animation on canvas:

```
Bitmap item;
.......
public Handler.Callback hc = new Handler.Callback() {
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    switch (msg.what) {
                    case 1:
                        if (ai == 8)
                            ai = 0;
                        item = bitmapArray.get(ai);
                        ++ai;
                        break;
```

maybe it is not call "optimization", and I had to say "readability"

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get()` just looks at a given position and returns whats there.
`add()` just adds what was passed to it.

There is no difference in

```
disk1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.disk01);
disk1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(disk1, 0, 0, origW, origH, matrix, true);
bitmapArray.add(disk1);
```

or

```
bitmapArray.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.disk01), 0, 0, origW, origH, matrix, true));
```

since the result of

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                            R.drawable.disk01), 0, 0, origW, origH, matrix, true));
```

is a Bitmap, regardles of saving it to an Bitmap object first or not.
It is like drinking from a bottle, you can fill it in a glas first, or drink directly from the bottle, in both cases you enjoy Cola or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Please check Java doc of `ArrayList` add method

> add(E e) 
>             Appends the specified element to the end of this list.

when add method is called object gets added in the `ArrayList`.

Now when you are retrieving it using

> get(int index) 
>             Returns the element at the specified position in this list.

It will return you the stored object it will not call the code written in the add method

Answer (score 0):

Collection.get returns an **object** stored in the given position. You can debug the process to learn more about this in details.

That saying, this

```
bitmapArray.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.disk01), 0, 0, origW, origH, matrix, true));
```

is the same as

```
disk1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.disk01);
disk1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(disk1, 0, 0, origW, origH, matrix, true);
bitmapArray.add(disk1);
```

In term of optimization, I believe both utilize pretty much the same amount of memory as an object will be created and store in the ArrayList anyway.